# Implementing "Command/Ctrl + F" web functionality in React Native or in React

Tags: reactjs, react-native, web, rxjs, react-native-navigation

Hello Guys I am trying to implement in the "Command/Ctrl + F" web functionality in React Native.

As you see in the Image there this "CTL +F" web functionality, I want that same functionality to attach to the search component. Like that highlighting and moving up and down to the text found the location.

I don't have any idea how to achieve this feature, need guidance. Thank you.

[image]